# php запускать команду в цикле каждые n секунд (php asterisk ami)

Tags: php, asterisk, timeout, sleep

Есть скрипт для мониторинга интерфейса AMI Asterisk. В нем есть несколько функций: get_response-получение данных из интерфейса, parse_response-поиск в данных нужного слова, parsetodb-запись в базу данных. Вот часть кода, которая слушает интерфейс:

```
while (1) {
$response=get_response($sock);
$parsed=parse_response($response, "Event");
switch ($parsed){
case "Newchannel":$parsed_event=parse_response($response, "Exten");
                foreach($phone_b as $v)
                if($parsed_event==$v)
                parsetodb($response,$columns);break;
case "QueueCallerJoin":
case "AgentConnect":
case "AgentComplete":
case "QueueCallerLeave":$parsed_event=parse_response($response, "Queue");
                foreach($queue as $v)
                if($parsed_event==$v)
                parsetodb($response,$columns);break;
case "HangupRequest":
case "SoftHangupRequest":$parsed_event=parse_response($response, "Exten");
                foreach($queue as $v)
                if($parsed_event==$v)
                parsetodb($response,$columns);break;}}
```

Проблема в том, что соединение закрывается после некоего времени простоя. Мне нужно вставить в цикл функцию "keepalive",которая будет каждые 60с отсылать специальные данные.Как мне это сделать, чтобы оно не повлияло на работу цикла? Возможно, какой то паралельный цикл?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вы не городили велосипед, советую вам ознакомиться с [PAMI](https://packagist.org/packages/marcelog/pami) и [React Event-Loop](https://packagist.org/packages/react/event-loop). И, думаю, ваши вопросы развеются сами собой.